# Is it possible to link movies that are fetched via API to comments that are stored in a separate database with Prisma and SQLite?

Tags: reactjs, api, sqlite, next.js, prisma

I am fetching some movies from the movie database via api and displaying them on my next js app. I want to create a comment system that will allow me to comment on each movie individually. I created a sqlite database using prisma and have only 1 model in the schema. I tried to comment on a movie but the comment was added and visible on all the movies and not just the one particular movie. I asked chatgpt for help and it told me to create another model in the schema in order to establish a connection/relation between the comment and the movie. Then i spent two hours trying to make it work (with the help of chatgpt) but to no avail. Then i thought that's maybe not possible to do it without having both the movies and comments uploaded to the same database so they can really be linked. I couldn't find anything on the internet about this. Is it possible to do it my way (fetching movies via api and creating a database to only store the comments and then someway linking them), or the only way is to have both on the database?

I was able to add comments to the database and show them on the front end page, but as i said, the same comments were published on all the different movies..

Answer (score 0):

Your movies surely have some kind of unique identifier, as fetched from that database. Simply add a column to your SQLite table (your prisma model) of comments and store the unique id of the movie it's about with each comment. Then, when your user asks for a particular movie, you can use its unique id to fetch the comments.

You'll need to present those comments in order, because comments of ten refer to previous comments. You can use an autoincrementing id to the order.

ORMs (prisma among many examples) are notorious for creating obfuscatory abstractions around simple IT concepts like tables. And ChatGPT doesn't know about that kind of thing. So it gives you back bs about bs. Be careful.